# Random Countdown timer

Tags: android, random, timer

I am pretty new on programing, and I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to make a random countdowntimer. This random countdowntimer was supposed to execute an object after the time (between 3-10 sec) has reached zero.And I really don´t know how to do that. Could someone please give me some examples on how I maybe could solve this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(random value, tick value) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {

            }

        }
    };
```

you can put random value as a value 3-10 its means onFinish called after this time

to create random value use code below

`Random r = new Random();
int randomInt = r.nextInt(10 - 3) + 3;`

Comment: Thank you guys for quick answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
int time = new Random().nextInt(8) + 3;

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // execute yor code
            }
        },time * 1000);
```

Use this. Hope help you.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, gonna test these out now!